# How to get joined model column in other model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on simple ASP .NET MVC web app which using Entity Framework ( DB First ).

First functionality I'm working on is "Room Booking".
For that, I have simple model:

```
public partial class Room
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public partial class Reservation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Stop { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public partial class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to create View like `UserReservations`, but I don't know how to get `User.UserName` and `Room.Name` in `Reservation`.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomId)
                //Here I want to have Room Name instead of RoomId.
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Start)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Stop)
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

How to get `Room.Name` in `Reservation` model ? Do I have to modyify it ( I think there would be modyfications in the future, so model will be updated from database and all of those changes would be discarded).

Comment: You will need to create another model that contains properties that your join query is returning.

Comment: if your models are configured correctly it should work like this: `reservationObject.Room.Name`

and the correct way should be `public partial class Reservation{ public int RoomId { get; set; } public Room Room {get;set;}}`

Comment: @Aarif model comes from database. If there would be any changes on database, app model will change itself too. Am i right ?

Comment: I think in this case adding a property `public Room Room {get; set;}` doesn't change anything on schema level it just provides us some ease at the code level, the relationship remains the same, have you tried it though?

Comment: @Aarif Yes I have. It causes errors saying that `Room` is not part of the current context, which I'm currently working with.

Comment: @Aarif I've just created my own class which has properties of type `Room`,`User` and `Reservation` and it works. Thanks for advice.

Comment: @fanarek Please add your controller method code to the question. This is a very simple problem.

Comment: You can view my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044937/how-to-use-2-models-in-a-view/51045717#51045717 . You need to use MVVM pattern in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

you can add manual navigation property to Reservation (add navigation property User and Room in Reservation), after that you have a user, room property to call User.UserName and Room.Name from Reservation :
[[Entity Framework - Add Navigation Property Manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465855/entity-framework-add-navigation-property-manually][1])

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreign key in your database.If you use foreign key between `Reservation->RoomId` and `Room->Id`, your Reservation class is like above.

```
public partial class Reservation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Stop { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Room Room{ get; set; } //your foreign table
}
```

And so you can use `Reservation.Room.Name` in your view